# How to get Cloth to ignore collisions with specific vertex groups?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I've got a thick cloth simulation, with a cage  that is simulated, then solidified, and my original model (With armature deformation) is mesh-deformed to the simulated cloth.
This works perfectly, but I need the simulated cloth to avoid colliding with the legs of the character, but if I add a collision modifier/physics to the original model, the simulated cloth collides with the jacket that's copying its deformation, so it goes haywire!

Here's the base pose:
[image]

Here's what it looks like with the simulation running:
[image]

And here's the clipping that I'm trying to get rid of:
[image]

Can I choose to ignore certain vertex groups in cloth collisions, between objects?

Comment: This is very difficult to picture from just your description. Could you upload a screenshot? A gif animation of the problem would be even better.

Comment: [Here it is when idle, the mesh cage in wireframe](http://i.imgur.com/zHvBITR.png),
[Here it is when simulated](http://i.imgur.com/9pOITiO.png), 
[And here's it causing clipping through the original model, the one it's influencing](http://i.imgur.com/CCONQCb.png)

Comment: (images now in the original post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to selectively ignore vertices, just add some collision objects that follow the legs. Create some super simple ellipsoid colliders that are parented to his thighs, knees, and/or calves and make them more-or-less the same size as the legs.

Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I'll try this! Seems like a pretty effective solution if I bind the whole object to the leg bones

Comment: I'd love to know how it works out!